# docker compose run mysql client against running mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am just getting into docker and have a simple mysql 5.5 set up using [the official image](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mysql). Here are my relevant files.

```
#Dockerfile
FROM mysql:5.5                                                                                                                             
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password

#docker-compose.yml
db:                                                                                                                                        
  build: .
```

Now I run `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up`
which gives the following output

```
db_1 | 150828 14:04:17 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1 | Version: '5.5.45'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Now in another terminal I run `docker-compose run db bash` and get into the bash shell. But in this shell if I try to connect the mysql client I get an error.

```
root@94a43b1f5be0:/# mysql -u root -p  

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

The same thing works with plain old docker. 
Example(Using the same Docker file):

```
docker build -t my-new-image .
docker run --name my-new-image-container -d my-new-image
docker exec -it my-new-image-container bash
root@8408282d162f:/# mysql -u root -p
mysql>
```

What am I doing wrong with docker-compose. How can I connect to my running mysql container and fire some queries. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `docker-compose run` actually starts up a new container, rather than connecting to the existing one. In this case, you've overridden the command with `bash`, so the mysql server hasn't started.

What you can do instead is just `docker exec` into the container given by `docker-compose ps`.

BTW, you don't need to build your own image here; you could just set the password in an environment variable in the `docker-compose.yml`. This would also have the advantage of not baking the password into the image.

Comment: Ah... this makes sense.. Thanks for the quick response